# SQL 3 column table, check if value X is in Y with fixed Z

Tags: sql, sql-server

When i have 3 column in my table "t" (X,Y,Z), i would like to see every row where a value x from X is in the column Y but for the same z from Z.

e.g.
X   Y   Z
1   2   1
1   1   1
2   1   2

Here the result would be the first row, because "1" is in Y in the second row for the same z of "1".

i tried something like:

```
select * from t  
where X = any (select Y from t)   
group by z;
```

but that is obviously wrong.

EDIT: Better example:

```
X    |       Y |    Z    
-----+---------+------------   
1    |       2 |    1  
6    |       1 |    6  
9    |       2 |    9  
3    |       1 |    1  
9    |       1 |    9
```

Here the return table should look like this

```
X    |      Y  |    Z    
-----+---------+------------   
1    |       2 |    1
```

because only the x value from the first row is somewhere in Y for a Z=1.

Comment: show your expected result

Comment: something like:    1 1 1

Comment: I can't help but say that it looks like an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Sorry there is no "deeper" problem behind this. I tried so solve for myself some self-made sql questions (for learning) but i couldn't solve this one. Thought it would be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this simply as:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.x in (select t2.y from t t2 where t2.z = t.z);
```

This seems like a direct translation of your question into SQL.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
declare @tb table(x int,y int,z int)
insert into @tb
select 1 ,2, 1 union all
select 1 ,1 ,1 union all
select 2, 1, 2


select a.z,a.x,b.y from @tb as a
inner join @tb  b
on a.x= b.y
group by a.z, a.x, b.y
```

result:

```
1   1   1
2   2   2
```

When i use to edit your query:

```
declare @tb table(x int,y int,z int)
insert into @tb
select 1 ,2, 1 union all
select 1 ,1 ,1 union all
select 2, 1, 2


select * from @tb
where x = any (select y from @tb)   
group by z,x,y;
```

result:

```
1   1   1
1   2   1
2   1   2
```

Comment: Okay that helped, i missed to join the table with itself again. Thx

Comment: I cannot figure out why aggregation would be appropriate for this problem.